# How to reset div data which I am appending on click?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here I want to reset the appended data on click. So I can get the fresh data by removing the old data. Now actually data is coming, but the new data is getting appended with the old data which I need to remove.

```js
$("#button").click(function(){

etc=$("#etc").val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'db4.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        etc: etc
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#div1').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
    },
    success: function(data) {

       var result = $.parseJSON((data));
       $.each(result,function(i,field){

           document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=field.name;
           $('body').append(document.getElementById("subasish123").innerHTML);
           $('#subasish123').slice(0).hide();
       });


       }
});
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="etc" type="text" name="etc">
  <label id="button">Click</label>
</form>
<div id="subasish123">
  <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#test').empty().append(...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but just now I have edited my code. Can u plz help me with the new code.

Comment: It's the same solution - use `.empty()` to clear out the contents of an element before you `append()` the new data

Comment: Its giving error ----TypeError: document.getElementById("subasish123").innerHTML is null

Comment: There is no element with the id of `subasish123` in the DOM when you run that line of code

Comment: So what to do now? any Idea..

Comment: You haven't given enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Actually I am fetching some values from database in json format which I need to display in HTML page. Its getting displayed but every time its getting appending new data with the old data. Just I need to reset the div when I click the button.

Comment: As I mentioned above, `empty()` is what you need to use. I don't see how that isn't solving your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting your output to some other element instead of `body`.
Emptying the `body` of your HTML wouldn't be desirable.

Look at this fiddle for example:

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/m1g5tn9g/)